# Scala - How AbstractSeq reduces bytecode size

Tags: java, scala, bytecode

I was going through scaladocs and came across `AbstractSeq` class. They describe it as

`Explicit instantiation of the Seq trait to reduce class file size in subclasses.`

How does this reduce file size of subclasses? Subclasses will get all the methods anyway right? Can someone explain how this works

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you extend a trait directly, the class gets a method for each method with implementation in a trait.

So let's say you have `N` methods with implementations in `Seq` (and traits `Seq` itself extends). If you have `M` classes extending `Seq`, they need `M*N` methods. When they extend `AbstractSeq`, `AbstractSeq` has `N` methods and all other classes inherit them. So you trade off 1 extra class for `(M-1)*N` fewer methods.